# How can I stop XmlReader.Create() from buffering results while deserializing an xml file to a C# model

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlreader

I use the following function to deserialize an xml document to a C# model:

```
 public XmlModel OpenModel(string filePath)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, readerSettings))
                return (XmlModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

I understand that `XmlReader.Create` is static. However, I thought that using the `using` function disposes the reader after each call. However, when I use this function more than once, the returning `XmlModel` is always buffered, duplicating the results. That is to say, the members of the `XmlModel` are a cumulation of the values read from the read xml file (`filePath`). If I call `XmlReader.Create` three times, I get the values tripled, etc.  I have used `reader.Close()` to no avail.

My application stores "state" values as XML. The user should be able to load a saved "state" and continue working from there. The first time a "state" is loaded, everything works fine. However, when a new "state" or xml file  is loaded, the application simply loads the last "state" plus the new "state" and I could trace this to the `XmlReader`. Maybe someone could be of help...

By the way, I use a similar function with `Json` and everything works fine ...

```
 public JsonModel OpenModel(string filePath)
        {
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(filePath))
                return (JsonModel)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(JsonModel));     
        }
```

*EDIT*

Here is more information which hopefully, will explain my problem in more detail. The information I have added show how I call the function and a sample xml file that I saved from my application ...

```
public  void Import()
{
    var file = FileExporting.GetFileFromLocation();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) && File.Exists(file))
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension) && string.Equals(extension, ".xml"))
        {
            // Get the xml model
            XmlModel model = new XmlSession().OpenModel(file) as XmlModel; // model is always a buffer, not what is desired

            // Load onto session
            ImportModel(model as XmlModel);

        }        
    }
}
```

*Session Class*

```
public class XmlSession
    {
        #region Private Members
        private readonly XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlModel));
        private static readonly XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings()
        {
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = @"    ",
            NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
            NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
        };

        private static readonly XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings()
        {
            CloseInput = true
        };

        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public XmlSession() { }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods


        public XmlModel OpenModel(string filePath)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, readerSettings))
                return (XmlModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        public void SaveModel(XmlModel model, string filePath)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, writerSettings))
                serializer.Serialize(writer, model);
        }

    }
```

*Sample Xml File*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XmlModel xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <head>
        <author>Max Mustermann</author>
        <date>7-16-2020</date>
        <copyright>All rights reserved - Max Mustermann Company</copyright>
        <application>Knowledge-Base</application>
        <name>C:\Users\MM\Downloads\Part.SLDPRT</name>
        <location>C:\Users\MM\Desktop\mre.xml</location>
    </head>
    <application>
        <versions>
            <version>1</version>
        </versions>
        <extensions>
            <extension>.xml</extension>
        </extensions>
    </application>
    <knowledgebase>
        <components>
            <component>
                <ObjectName>Part</ObjectName>
                <ObjectType>Component</ObjectType>
                <IsHeader>false</IsHeader>
                <PersistId>200050000000005000000000255254255000000000000000</PersistId>
                <Notes>A cad component</Notes>
                <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
                <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
                <IsSuppressed>false</IsSuppressed>
                <Attributes>
                    <ObjectAttribute>
                        <Name>Material</Name>
                        <Domain>Text</Domain>
                        <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Iron</Value>
                        <AttributeNotes>Some notes</AttributeNotes>
                    </ObjectAttribute>
                </Attributes>
                <ThisDimensionValue>123</ThisDimensionValue>
            </component>
        </components>
        <project />
        <company />
        <customer />
        <rules />
    </knowledgebase>
</XmlModel>
```

*2nd EDIT*

The `ImportModel` method

```
private  void ImportModel(XmlModel xmlModel)
{
    if (CapturedObjects.Items.Any())
    {
        var userInput = ShowMessageBox("Current information in memory will be cleard. Do you want to continue?", MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (userInput == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    // Get the knowledge-base
    var KnowledgeBase = xmlModel.XmlBase;

    // Clear
    CapturedObjects.Items.Clear();
    CapturedObjects.ProjectInformation = null;
    CapturedObjects.CustomerInformation = null;
    CapturedObjects.ProjectInformation = null;

    // Get components
    foreach (var i in KnowledgeBase.Components)
    {
        CapturedObjects.Items.Add(i);
    }

    // Get Customer information
    CapturedObjects.CustomerInformation = KnowledgeBase.Customer;

    // Get Company information
    CapturedObjects.CompanyInformation = KnowledgeBase.Company;

    // Get Project Information
    CapturedObjects.ProjectInformation = KnowledgeBase.Project;

}
```

Comment: How are you calling it? What does the input look like? Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates how calling `OpenModel` (the first one) multiple times does not behave as you expect.

Comment: @madreflection Unfortunately I can't edit my question to add the infos you have requested. Anyways, I call as such: `XmlModel model = new XmlSession().OpenModel(file) as XmlModel;`

Comment: If you're concerned about proprietary information, keep in mind that the point of a [mre] is to reduce the problem to its fundamental pieces. Start a new project with just enough to reproduce the problem and none of the proprietary information you can't share. It will greatly improve your chances of getting the help you need.

Comment: Showing one call doesn't help if you're saying that multiple calls don't behave the way you want. That's too minimal, such that it's not reproducible.

Comment: Please review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly the section entitled "**Help others reproduce the problem**". [Edit] details into your question; don't link to them or leave them in comments.

Comment: Show us `ImportModel` method.

Comment: I switched from `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlModel));` to `DataContractSerializer dcserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(XmlModel));` and the problem disappeared. This means that the trouble is most probably wiith the `XmlSerializer`!

Comment: The problem is that the DataContractSerializer does not support attributes for speed concerns ... see [XmlSerializer vs DataContractSerializer](http://web.archive.org/web/20130430190551/http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a List then add each file to the list so you save all the data and not overwrite the results.

Use following to do Xml Serialize

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlModel));
            List<XmlModel> models = new List<XmlModel>();
            XmlModel model = (XmlModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            models.Add(model);            }
    }
    public class XmlModel
    {
        public Head head { get; set; }
        public Application application { get; set; }
        public Knowledgebase knowledgebase { get; set; }
    }
    public class Head
    {
        public string author { get; set; }

        private DateTime _date { get; set; }
        public string date 
        { 
            get {return _date.ToString("M-dd-yyyy");} 
            set {_date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "M-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);} 
        }
        public string copyright { get; set; }
        public string application { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
    }
    public class Application
    {
        [XmlArray("versions")]
        [XmlArrayItem("version")]
        public string[] versions { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("extensions")]
        [XmlArrayItem("extension")]
        public string[] extensions { get; set; }
    }
    public class Knowledgebase
    {
        [XmlArray("components")]
        [XmlArrayItem("component")]
        public Component[] component { get; set; }

        public string project { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string customer { get; set; }
        public string rules { get; set; }
    }
    public class Component
    {
        public string ObjectName { get; set; }
        public string ObjectType { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsHeader { get; set; }
        public string PersistId { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsVisible { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsHidden { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsSuppressed { get; set; }
        public int ThisDimensionValue { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("Attributes")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ObjectAttribute")]
        public Attribute[] attribute { get; set; }
    }
    public class Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string AttributeNotes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your response. This unfortunately does not solve my problem. In fact, my serialization and deserialization  work work fine. The main problem is that after the first call to `XmlReader.Create(fileName)`, the reader seems not to get disposed but rather buffers the results. This means that in this line: `XmlModel model = (XmlModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader);` the model is always a cumulation of the xml read whereas I expect this to be just the contents of the actual/current file (`fileName`) that is read ...

Comment: c# object are not released unless all links to the object are removed.  The class objects have links to parents and the Garbage Collection does not dispose an object unless there is one parent (the current class).  Putting code into a "using" block or adding to a class a Dispose method will call GC to remove an object when parent count is one.

Comment: That is my understanding too. In the `XmlSession` class provided in my question, you will see that I made use of the `using` block. I also tried to explicitly close the reader `reader.Close()` to no avail. I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong - I need to figure out what! The application works fine if the user loads a "state" (xml file) the first time. If the same "state" is reloaded or another "state" is loaded, the expected behavior is for the current memory to be cleared and the new "state" loaded into memory. However, the `model` provides cumulated values, as already indicated!

Comment: You issue is with this line : ImportModel(model as XmlModel);  You can change to : XmlModel model = ImportModel(file) and then open file in the ImportMode method.

Comment: Tried that to no avail. After running through the debug mode in VS, I think the culprit is either `XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, readerSettings)` or `(XmlModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader)` in the `public XmlModel OpenModel(string filePath)` method because the return value of this method is the problem!

Comment: I switched from `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlModel));` to 
`DataContractSerializer dcserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(XmlModel));` and the problem disappeared. This means that the trouble is most probably wiith the `XmlSerializer`!

Comment: It turns our that the `DataContractSerializer` is providing me with much more thatn needed headache. I read this today [link](http://dotnetcodebox.blogspot.com/2013/01/xmlserializer-class-may-result-in.html#comment-form), tried it but same problem! Is there someone out there who can help??

Comment: What are the headaches? The xml serializer is slow and uses a lot of memory but work fine.  If you are having issues then I suspect the xml being returned is different from the one posted.  The serializer also requires more classes than other parsing methods.  I need to know exactly what you classes to do the job correctly.

Comment: After following our discussion here, I solved the problem by selecting distinct values to be viewed by the user. This works well (at least for now.) I will mark this answer as the correct answer as it led me to finding a solution. Thanks for your patience and support!